# Why can't I mount this efs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

I have used this CDK setup (https://github.com/doctorray117/minecraft-ondemand) to build an AWS based minecraft bedrock server. All i need to do is be able to transfer the existing world files to this new server instance but when I try to mount the efs in the existing ec2 server (running ubunto 20) so I can manage the files it times out.

I have checked that TCP port 2049 is open inbound on the efs security group and also that it is allowed outbound on the existing ec2 UBUNTU 20 server.

Tried various approaches...

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport 123.456.789.00:/ /mnt/minecraft-on-demand
```

This times out.

```
sudo -E mount -t efs -o tls,accesspoint=fsap-123456789 fs-123456789/mnt/minecraft-on-demand
```

and

```
sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-123456789:/ /mnt/minecraft-on-demand
```

gives
"Connection to the mount target IP address 12.34.56.78 timeout. Please retry in 5 minutes if the mount target is newly created. Otherwise check your VPC and security group configuration to ensure your file system is reachable via TCP port 2049 from your instance.

I'm no AWS expert so I'm a bit stumped as to what to do next and searching online always flags up opening 2049 in the security groups whcih I have done.

Comment: It's most likely outgoing instance security group being matched with the incoming efs security group. Could also be instance firewall.